# Unable to Save or Publish new modern pages in Sharepoint 2019 on-prem

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, modern-pages

Sharepoint Server 2019 no longer has any buttons to Save or Publish new pages created with Add New Page (non-wiki). It is somewhat puzzling, as I am still able to create new lists, doc libraries and even subsites. Somehow got locked out of the ability to add a new modern page.

Any clues what to look for in the settings, perhaps some update did this?

Comment: Does the pages library have unique permissions?

Comment: Checked the permissions, happening in every site and subsite of the portal. The Site Pages library inherits permissions from the parent site. No unique permissions set. Many thanks!

Comment: Whether you did a upgrade before? And you could install the latest CU, then have a test.

Comment: @EmilyDu-MSFT thank you, after months of struggle, at last the Save and Publish buttons have returned after installation of August CUs for the Core and Language Dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.